# UnrealEngine how to create pirate boat tutorial

Tags: udk, unreal, unreal-4

I fount an Unity [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s_RIfCfMlPc) how to crate pirate boat, but I still can't find any sources (links, videos) how to create it using UE.

Kind of [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7_cFo8-RkaA). So when you use character controller it can jump, run and etc, but with a boat you should smoothly running trough the waves with some bouncing effects. So I try to find tutorial that describe how to create this pirate boat. So the question not about model, so I can even use a cube that I can move through waves.

Comment: You notice that unity is not the unreal engine, yes? Probably the boat can be downloaded via the unity asset's store.

Comment: Is how to make a boat or how to make water you're looking for? The 2nd video doesn't exactly make that clear.

Comment: Question is too broad.  How to create a boat?  You need to expand on your question in order for anyone to be able to help.

Answer (score 2):

To do the same as the Unity tutorial you mention, you need to use a Pawn (not a Character!) with your boat mesh.

Then, use the `SetupPlayerInputComponent` function to get your inputs (or just your input node if you're using Bluprints).

You can now `AddMovementInput` to your Pawn, and it should perfectly move.

Your can use `AddControllerYawInput` to make your Boat turn right or left.

Comment: yea cool I will check this, but maybe you know also some links with examples, maybe video)

Comment: I didn't found anything about boats, but maybe [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cPVaDndT7tY) could help you. It's not  really a boat, but you can just ignore the "hover" effect (It's done in BP, but you can surely convert it to c++ if you want). You should also take a look at the simple vehicle template in the engine.